# Appliances from Saudi Arabia in Europe?

Tags: voltage, frequency, voltage-measurement, frequency-measurement

I got my hands on a Xbox Series S on my trip to Saudi Arabia and now that I am going back home I came to a sudden realization that electricity is in a different configuration to the one in my home country - it's 240V 60Hz!

In my home country it's typical 220V 50Hz configuration...

Would that mean if I use it back home that it can potentially get damaged?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No need to worry. The Xbox is driven by a switch mode power supply the first thing it does is to rectify the mains in and convert it to DC. So it does not matter whether this is 50 or 60Hz.

It would matter if there was an AC synchronous motor in the appliance driven directly from the mains this would attempt to run 20% slower potentially causing problems.

Answer (score -2):

It depends. Some appliances have automatic sensing and will change without you doing anything. Look in the documentation.
Some equipment have switches to select the voltage/frequency. Look around near the cord and again look in the documentation.